# Advantages of 7400 series ICs over diode logic?

Tags: digital-logic, diodes, 7400

I can use diode logic (DRL) or 7400-series logic ICs when I need OR gate or AND gate.
Say 74HC08, 74HC11, 74HC21 (AND gates), or 74HC32 (OR gates).

Diode logic seems to me simpler, cheaper and thus better. I prefer it in my small MCU projects.

But I wonder if there are some general advantages of 7400-series compared to diode logic that I do not see.

**UPDATE:**
I was actually thinking about particular problem, but I tried to ask general question. And that was a mistake.
So, in the beginning, I was thinking about these circuits:
[image: diode logic]
[image: 7400 series logic]
I wanted to trigger interrupt on PIC MCU which has only 1 port capable of interrupt by multiple buttons.

Comment: Have you ever tried to cascade a few diode logic gates?

Comment: As  I just had a discussion over what your question really means: Do you mean diode-transistor logic (which you can also buy in IC packages or can build with discrete components) or do you mean diode-resistor logic (which you very probably can not buy as ICs)? I ask because it's incredibly hard to justify comparing Diode-R-logic to logic ICs – there's loads and loads of *functional* differences.

Comment: What exactly do you name "diode logic"? Extension of 7400 gate for more inputs using some diodes? Noise immunity will be worse using diodes to get more inputs.

Comment: I mean DRL. Just discretes used.

Comment: The diodes shown in your first schematic don't do anything.  If the switches were SPDT, choosing +5V or ground they would be needed. Your arrangement, with SPST, has them choosing +5V or an open circuit.

Comment: There is pull-down resistor which keeps INT port low. As soon as you push any of the buttons, INT port is pulled high. So, it behaves like OR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Diode logic seems to me simpler, cheaper and thus better. I prefer it in my small MCU projects.

I'm amazed you can still buy diode logic at all – it was practically obsolete by the late 1960s.

The reason is simply: diode logic needs higher voltages and currents to operate, and is usually, compared to cheap modern devices, much slower.

I can't really find an example of a logic IC that is cheaper in diode logic variant than in CMOS/TTL. So your impression of "cheap" might simply be based on whoever sells you the ICs you're using.

To be honest, this is a typical hobbyist question: *Using 1960's logic ICs isn't normal, but on electronics magazines and ham radio schematics, it is*.

TL;DR: Diode logic is inferior to 7400 in TTL and CMOS versions (like the 74HC**) in the following categories:

- Power,
- Speed,
- Voltage,
- Availability, and
- usually, cost.

Also, if I'm not mistaken, regarding your specific application *in small MCU projects*: MCUs need additional drivers to even put out roughly 5V as needed by DTL. MCUs that offer these drivers are relatively uncommon these days – the ATMega series springs to mind, but not much else. Is it possible you save a few cents on logic ICs, but pay a couple Euros extra on the MCU, just so that it can drive 5V?

Comment: Indeed, today, you don't "buy" [diode logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode_logic). You build it with discretes. At least I think this is what OP meant. And this makes it an even worse choice compared to regular logic ICs: (takes up more PCB space, more BOM lines, doesn't buffer the signal, ...).

Comment: @dim wait: is he really referring to DRL, not DTL? Then, on one hand, the question makes more sense (why use a 14 pin IC if I just need two diodes for an OR?) and less sense (why compare two diodes to something that is actually a logic device, with proper buffering, no dependency on sinking loads of current (I mean, HC series))!

Comment: This is what I understood when reading OP's post, yes. But it is not said clearly, so I'm not really sure. You might want to ask for clarification.

Comment: Yes, DRL is what I meant. Just discretes.

Comment: @Chupacabras Then, it's a bit like comparing apple and oranges. But, by combining Marcus's answer and the various comments, you certainly now have an idea of the advantages of 74xx over DRL. Do you? I hope you do...

Comment: Well, yes, I can take something from opinions and comments.

Comment: well, the most important aspect here is that you cannot concatenate diode logic, because every diode reduces the voltage by it's forward voltage (typically 0.7V). As soon as you add transistors back in to boost the voltage levels, your cost and complexity advantage gets eliminated. Also, 7004 logic has a lot of nice features, like noise/ringing-resistant Schmitt trigger inputs etc.

Comment: I have updated my question.